# Difficulty plotting a function with ParamericPlot3D

Tags: plotting

This works:

```
With[{a = 5, b = 2}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[{(a + b Cos[t]) Cos[s], (a + b Cos[t]) Sin[s], 
   b Sin[t]}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

Producing this image:

[image]

Then I created this function:

```
T[s_, t_] := {(a + b Cos[t]) Cos[s], (a + b Cos[t]) Sin[s], b Sin[t]}
```

And it works:

```
T[s, t]
```

Output is: {Cos[s] (a + b Cos[t]), (a + b Cos[t]) Sin[s], b Sin[t]}

Then I tried:

```
With[{a = 5, b = 2}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[T[s, t], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

Which produced this image:

[image]

So, it didn't work. I also tried:

```
With[{a = 5, b = 2}, 
     ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@T[s, t], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

But that also didn't work. I am using Mathematica 11.2. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** Thanks to the help below, this works and produces the same image:

```
T[a_, b_][s_, t_] := {(a + b Cos[t]) Cos[s], (a + b Cos[t]) Sin[s], 
   b Sin[t]};
With[{a = 5, b = 2}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[T[a, b][s, t], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

Comment: I think that the problem is that `a` and `b` are local variables and they are not assigned to `T[s,t]`. This definition works obviously `T[s_, t_, a_, b_] := {(a + b Cos[t]) Cos[s], (a + b Cos[t]) Sin[s], 
  b Sin[t]}`. I just see there is the same answer

Answer (score 2):

`With` works like `Module`, i.e. creating local variables, whereas parameters `a` and `b` in function T are global (not inside `With`).

Consider the following example:

```
In[1]:=   G := {a, b};
          With[{a = 5, b = 2}, {{a, b}, G}]

Out[1]:= {{5, 2}, {a, b}}
```

There are several possible workarounds.

1. You pass parameters `a` and `b` *somehow* to `T`:

   ```
   In[2]:=  T[a_, b_][s_, t_] := {(a + b Cos[t])Cos[s], (a + b Cos[t])Sin[s], b Sin[t]};
            With[{a = 5, b = 2}, T[a, b][s, t]]

   Out[2]:= {Cos[s] (5 + 2 Cos[t]), (5 + 2 Cos[t]) Sin[s], 2 Sin[t]}
   ```
2. You use local *replacement rule* instead of actual variables.

   ```
   In[3]:=  T[s_, t_] := {(a + b Cos[t]) Cos[s], (a + b Cos[t]) Sin[s], b Sin[t]};
            With[{sub = {a -> 5, b -> 2}}, T[s, t] /. sub]

   Out[3]:= {Cos[s] (5 + 2 Cos[t]), (5 + 2 Cos[t]) Sin[s], 2 Sin[t]}
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added an update of what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution:

```
T[s_, t_, a_, b_] := {(a + b Cos[t]) Cos[s], (a + b Cos[t]) Sin[s],b Sin[t]}

With[{a = 5, b = 2}, ParametricPlot3D[T[s, t, a, b], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```